# If you add a non-member to a circle in Google+, do they get an email notification?

Tags: google-plus

If I add someone from my Gmail contacts to a circle, and they haven't got a Google+ account, do they get an email saying I've added them on Google+?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they don't get a notification. However, when you share to that Circle, Google will ask if you want to send an email update to people not using Google +.

Comment: Also, when you add them to the Circle you'll be gently prompted to invite them to Google+. If you do, _then_ they'll get an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

As of this post they do, in fact, receive an email, if you add them from within Gmail. I made the mistake of adding an important client to a Circle with an accidental click, and they received an invite to join Google+. That resulted in a very awkward phone conversation where they were letting me down easy about how they don't use Google+, and I was letting them down easy that I wasn't inviting them to my social network.

I wrote an extension to prevent this from happening again that disables the button:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-gmail-add-to-circ/nckhnfmcmenbmoabnfcmdiabconcbhdk